# DBSCAN clustering algorithm not working properly. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, data-mining, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am trying to write the DBSCAN algorithm to cluster a set of points, but the results I am getting are really bad. This could be because of the data, but it's not just that. I am getting clusters of size < minPoints which should not happen.

What am I doing wrong? I have gone through the code many times, and I cannot figure out what the problem is.

I referred the algorithm given on the [DBSCAN Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN#Pseudocode).

```
private static int[] dbScan(String[] points, int epsilon, int minPts) {
    int cluster = 0;
    // visited stores if point has been visited
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[points.length];
    // pointsCluster stores which cluster a point has been assigned to
    int[] pointsCluster = new int[points.length];
    for(int iii = 0; iii < points.length; iii++) {
        // if point iii is already visited, do nothing  
        if(visited[iii]) continue;                      
        visited[iii] = true;    // mark point iii as visited
        // get points in neighborhood of point iii
        HashSet<Integer> neighbors = epsilonNeighbors(points, iii, epsilon);    
        if(neighbors.size() < minPts) {
            // if number of neighbors < minPts, mark point iii as noise
            pointsCluster[iii] = -1;
        } else {
            ++cluster;                      // else, start new cluster
            expandCluster(points, iii, neighbors, pointsCluster, visited, cluster, epsilon, minPts);
        }
    }
    return pointsCluster;
}

/*
 * Expands a cluster if a point is not a noise point
 * and has > minPts in its epsilon neighborhood
 */
private static void expandCluster(String[] points, int seedPoint, HashSet<Integer> neighbors,
        int[] pointsCluster, boolean[] visited, int cluster, int epsilon, int minPts) {

    pointsCluster[seedPoint] = cluster;     //assign cluster to seed point
    // create queue to process neighbors
    Queue<Integer> seeds = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    seeds.addAll(neighbors);
    while(!seeds.isEmpty()) {
        int currentPoint = (Integer) seeds.poll();
        if(!visited[currentPoint]) {
            visited[currentPoint] = true;       // mark neighbor as visited
            // get neighbors of this currentPoint
            HashSet<Integer> currentNeighbors = epsilonNeighbors(points, currentPoint, epsilon);
            // if currentPoint has >= minPts in neighborhood, add those points to the queue
            if(currentNeighbors.size() >= minPts) {
                seeds.addAll(currentNeighbors);
            }
        }
        // if currentPoint has not been assigned a cluster, assign it to the current cluster
        if(pointsCluster[currentPoint] == 0) pointsCluster[currentPoint] = cluster;
    }
}

/*
 * Returns a HashSet containing the indexes of points which are
 * in the epsilon neighborhood of the point at index == currentPoint
 */
private static HashSet<Integer> epsilonNeighbors(String[] points, int currentPoint, int epsilon) {
    HashSet<Integer> neighbors = new HashSet<Integer>();
    String protein = points[currentPoint];
    for(int iii = 0; iii < points.length; iii++) {
        int score = similarity(points[iii], points[jjj]);
        if(score >= epsilon) neighbors.add(iii);
    }
    return neighbors;
}
```

Comment: Also consider looking at the original publications, instead of Wikipedia!

Answer (score 1):

When your results are bad, it might be because your data is bad (for density based clustering), or because your parameters are bad.

In fact, DBSCAN *can* produce clusters smaller than minPts, if they touch each other. They can then "steal" border points from one another.

How about using e.g. [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) to verify your algorithm output?

Comment: Wow, you're right. I didn't think about clusters "stealing" border points. Thanks a lot.
So, from the looks of it, the algorithm looks fine, right?

Comment: I didn't check it in detail. And your `epsilonNeighbors` references the undefined variable `jjj`. Also note that Java collections perform really bad with primitive types. You really might want to try ELKI, because it's really really fast.

Comment: Yes, that `jjj` is supposed to be `currentPoint`. Will look into ELKI. Thanks for your help.